# Converting string to array table data php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, pcre

I currently am trying to convert customer purchases from a pdf table to editable table data. 
I have now an array that has each row as its element by using **preg_match_all()**

```
array(234) {[0]=> string(111) "16842 90143020 7.1.2018 Customer-1 Denver A12345678A 3.900 0 0 0 0 5.000 5.150 0 0 0 0 0 0" [1] =>....}
```

Each string delimitted by spaces is a cell value that will correspond to a colmun eg.:

```js
ID => 16842; OrderID => 90143020; Date => 7.1.2018; CustomerName => 'Customer-1'; Location => 'Denver'; ClientID => 'A12345678A'; Payment => 3.900 AdditionalPayment => 0;.....
```

The easiest way is to explode by /space/. But what if I have a Customer Name:
Not like 'CustomerOne' but 'Customer One' or 'Customer One One' eg. "Billy's CoffeShop". It has a /space/ now, and each word will convert as a separate cell

Comment: And now imagine Billy's Coffee Shop not being located in Denver, but Salt Lake City ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are extracting string from the table. However, if you try to get the info delimited by "," it would be easier to separate cells.

Comment: im using **preg_match** to extract each table row by knowing what is the position of a specific pattern